# Animate the flying of a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios

When a tableview cell is touched, I want the text of the cell to fly to a new location. But this doesn't seem to work. Please advice what is going wrong here.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.tableView1 deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];    
    CGRect cellRect = [cell.superview convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.view];
    // The cell should be shown in table as well, so create a new cell    
    UITableViewCell *view1 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:cellRect];
   [self.view addSubview:view1];
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0
                      options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                      animations:^{
                     view1.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 0, 0);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                     [view1 removeFromSuperview];
                     [self songAddedToQ:indexPath];
                 }];
}
```

Comment: You are animating an empty cell. I doubt that is what you want.

Comment: I tried adding text to cell, by doing view1.textLabel.text = cell.textLabel.text but some how it never worked. Finally I ended up taking a screenshot of the cell rect and animating that image view.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is how I solved it.

```
-(UIImage*) returnCellImage:(UITableViewCell*)cell
{    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [cell.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return screenShot;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.tableView1 deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *image = [self returnCellImage:cell];
    CGRect cellRect = [cell.superview convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.view];
    UIImageView *view1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cellRect];
    [view1 setImage:image];
    [self.view addSubview:view1];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0
                      options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                      animations:^{
                          view1.frame = CGRectMake(10,10, 0, 0);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [view1 removeFromSuperview];
                 }];

}
```

Comment: is there a way to disable the default animations ? I want full custom actions.

Comment: Please elaborate full custom actions. What you want to do.

Comment: When I delete a collection view cell, can you disable the "generic fade out" e.g u want you cell to float down and off screen.

Comment: I'll just animate the cell, and then in the completion of animation i'll delete it from my MOC/FRC and that should be easiest way.